# How can I deactivate set and attributes be loaded by hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm currently having problems with hibernate when jackson generate json object. Is it possible to disable hibernate attribute loading on a specific query?

Comment: The solution you have in mind is most probably not the right one for the actual problem you have. Post your code, tell us what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Actually, I use a table linked to many other tables. I access the data with only one query with success. But when jackson serealize the objects, lazy loading query the db. If I deactivate lazy loading, the full database is loaded. I'm looking for a soution not using @jsonIgnore anotation

Comment: JsonIgnore looks like one of the right solutions to me. Or a DTO. Or the Jackson Hibernate module configured not to serialize uninitialized proxies. Or a JSON view.